# Increase margins between plot and dropdown widget in Jupyter notebook.

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, kaggle, ipywidgets

I'm basically just trying to place some room between my plots and a dropdown widget in a Jupyter notebook. Currently the plots are covering up the dropdown boxes. Here is link to the notebook on Kaggle-  https://www.kaggle.com/samdotson/exploratory-analysis-with-geopandas/, a screenshot and some example code. I'm aware that the interactive component is disabled in Kaggle, so you'll have to fork it if you want run the code to make the widgets appear.

Additionally if you have any suggestions for how to enable the user interactivity, that would be incredibly helpful. For now I'm just trying to resolve the margin issue.

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHYwG.jpg)

```
def f(x='Median Age-Total Population', y='Median Value (Dollars)'):
    x_abbr = labels.loc[labels['label'] == x , 'abbreviated'].iloc[0]
    y_abbr = labels.loc[labels['label'] == y , 'abbreviated'].iloc[0] 
    x_values= ((Lincoln_blk_groups.iloc[:,Lincoln_blk_groups.columns== x_abbr]).values)
    y_values= ((Lincoln_blk_groups.iloc[:,Lincoln_blk_groups.columns== y_abbr]).values)
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(x_values, y_values)
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi= 80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, color = 'red')
    plt.plot(x_values, regressor.predict(x_values), color = 'blue')
    plt.title(x + " versus " + y +" in Lincoln, NE", fontsize=25 )
    plt.xlabel(x , fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel( y , fontsize=15)
    plt.show()
interact(f,x=labels.iloc[:,1], y=labels.iloc[:,1])
```

Comment: I forked your Kaggle code and ran it. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/RDMpHCk.png) is the screenshot. The dropdowns don't look messed up. So could it be that you are on some high resolution display  or some other resolution issue?

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look at into this. Thank you.

Comment: Okay so it would seem the issue only occurs with Chrome, things look fine in Edge and Firefox.

Comment: Yes. I checked in Firefox as well.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this is a very strange issue. Perhaps I should inform someone about a bug...